# ASP.NET: Image URL is correct, but image does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-uploading, web-controls

I know this has been asked before, as it's a rookie question, but the other answers on here did not clarify it for me.  I an uploading a file then providing a preview.  The click event of my upload button is this:

```
protected void UploadFile (object sender, EventArgs e) {

    string folderPath = Server.MapPath ("~/Uploads/");

    // If folder does not exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists (folderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory (folderPath);         

    //Save the File to the Directory (Folder).
    FileUpload.SaveAs (folderPath + Path.GetFileName (FileUpload.FileName));

    //Display the Picture in Image control.
    imgItem.ImageUrl = folderPath + Path.GetFileName (FileUpload.FileName);
}
```

The upload works fine, but the image control (imgItem) does not display the picture.  When I trace it, the URL looks perfect.  The URL is:

```
"C:\\MyStuff\\Source\\Inventory\\Inventory\\UserInterface\\Uploads\\sample.jpg"
```

That should have worked.  What in the world am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  I don't feel that this is a good solution at all, but I've found that the program works as expected if I change the last line to this:

```
imgItem.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName (FileUpload.FileName);
```

Don't anyone have a cleaner, less hardcodey solution?

Comment: "C:\blah\blah" is not "perfect". That's the opposite of what you want. The page is going to be viewed on the end user's computer. They're not going to have this file on their machine at "C:\blah\blah". Instead you have to provide them a URL to a path that you're actually serving the file to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I didn't actually reference the drive letter.  It's a relative path, so it does exist on the server.

Comment: yes, you did reference the drive letter. Did you look at what `Server.MapPath ("~/Uploads/")` is giving you?

Comment: Okay, I see your point.  So how do I redirect it to point to the server?

Comment: You already figured it out. It's the "hardcodey solution" you posted. You already hardcoded the path to `~/Uploads/` above it and you didn't seem to balk at that, so I don't understand why you're doing so here. You could of course change it to take a path from configuration or use a const or some other means of getting the base path, but the general idea is what you've already shown.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to web development and just figure that everything I do probably shows it.  Trying to find reasonable, acceptable solutions when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imgItem.ImageUrl = "~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName (FileUpload.FileName);

Answer (score 0):

Well, the

> "C:\MyStuff\Source\Inventory\Inventory\UserInterface\Uploads\sample.jpg"

is actually the file path, not the URL. Since you use the word "URL", I assume that you're building a web site. Which means you need an proper URL (e.g.  http(s)://yourdomain.com/Source/Inventory/..../sample.jpg)

If you don't how what is the url for your file path, you can use virtual folder in IIS to map it. https://docs.kentico.com/k11/installation/deploying-kentico-to-a-live-server/creating-virtual-directories-and-application-pools-in-iis-7-5-and-7-0